# Git clone and overwrite local repository

Tags: git

I would like to have an up to date copy (periodically) of the bitbucket repo on my server, but not sure which git commands I have to issue to avoid potential merge conflicts that can happen with pulls.
The only clean way I can think of is to clone to a tmp dir then copy/overwrite local repo.
But there must be a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merge conflicts occur when—and *only* when—you do merge-like operations, such as:

- rebasing your commits
- merging your commits with someone else's, or vice versa
- using `git revert` to revert commits, so as to make your own branches that differ from theirs

Note the common theme here: you must have *your own* commits, of your own work (or of reversions of specific parts of theirs, but again these are *your* commits that you are adding).

Thus, if you never make your own commits, you will never have any conflicts.  Of course, this means you can never make any changes—or if you do make changes, you must keep them on *your* branches, always separate from *their* branches.

But that's exactly what Git does in the first place, *as long as you avoid running `git merge`* (and `git rebase` and so on).

The `git pull` command consists of a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`.  (Well, you can configure it, or tell it, to use `git rebase` instead of `git merge`.  But you don't want either one.)  So ... don't use `git pull`.

This is good advice for anyone new to Git: *avoid `git pull`*, because it does *two* things, and you want to do one thing, then ponder a bit about whether you want *any* second thing, much less `git merge` or `git rebase` as the second thing.

As in [janos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38784349/1256452), if you have made no commits of your own, but want your current branch to match `origin/master` exactly, you can simply `git reset --hard`.  Note that when you run `git fetch`—I recommend `git fetch origin`, not `git fetch origin master`<sup>1</sup>—your Git will pick up *all* of their branches, but *rename* them all: their `master` becomes your `origin/master`, their `develop` becomes your `origin/develop`, their `feature/thing` becomes your `origin/feature/thing`, and so on.

If you *do* want, and therefore make, commits of your own, on your own branches, just make sure you don't name them `origin/whatever` (which will be confusing<sup>2</sup>) and don't try to merge or rebase them in any way until you are sure that's a good idea.

---

<sup>1</sup>In current/modern Git, adding `master` restricts your Git to picking up just their `master`, and your Git updates `origin/master` as usual.  In older (pre-1.8.4) versions of Git, adding `master` restricts your Git the same way, but *also* makes it *not* update `origin/master`.  So you get their work, which you immediately forget all about, which does you no good.  Getting only `master` saves you a little network time, and then you waste hours trying to figure out why you didn't get *anything*, only to discover that your chosen Linux distribution ships with a 400-year-old<sup>3</sup> version of Git, for some unfathomable reason. :-)

<sup>2</sup>*Git* won't get confused—it knows local and remote-tracking branches just fine—but it sure will be confusing for *humans* to have `origin/bruce` as a local branch and a different `origin/bruce` as a remote-tracking branch.

<sup>3</sup>Slight exaggeration for humor.

Comment: so you're saying that if I only do pulls on this local repo, and no commits - no matter how many people commit to remote, I won't get merge conflict locally on pull?

Comment: Beautiful answer (+1). But I still think the main recommendation should be `git fetch origin master` and `git fetch origin` be secondary (only for old versions)

Comment: @vani: I'm saying *don't use `git pull`*. Pull means merge! You just said you want to avoid merges! *If* your upstream is disciplined and never uses force-push to "remove" commits, the merge that `pull` runs will never do a real merge and you'll be OK. But ***if not***, you risk doing a real merge, with attendant merge conflicts. This means you are depending on someone else. You can use `git reset` as in @janos' answer, instead, and hence not depend on anyone else.

Comment: @janos: do you find this saves a lot of time? I've found it rarely saves anything: usually any extra expense from fetching other branches pays at least most of its cost back later when those commits get merged.  I pay about 5 seconds now and about 2 seconds tomorrow instead of about 3 seconds now and about 3.5 seconds tomorrow.  Sure, 6.5 is a bit less than 7, but I spend more time than that backspacing over typos. :-) It may depend a lot on the nature of your repositories, I suppose.

Comment: @vani I really think you should accept torek's answer instead of mine. It's a much more detailed treatment of your situation, and by far a superset of what I wrote (+humor).

Comment: @janos: I do the same (`git fetch`), but I often have several remotes set so that I end up having to run several `git fetch`-es, or define a remote group or whatever. I used to think pre-version-2.0 Git was rare but certain unnamed cough*centos*cough distributions still ship with 1.7.x!

Answer (score 14):

Instead of cloning to a tmp dir and then replacing your local repository with that new clone,
you can *fetch* from the remote and *hard-reset* your local:

```
git fetch origin master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

There won't be merge conflicts, as you're simply taking whatever is in `origin/mater`.